# Wait for server response with axios from different file React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a loop. On each round I need to add *Question* data into MongoDB database. This works fine. However, I want to get *_id* of the new inserted *Question* before the loop goes into the next round. This is where I have a problem. It takes certain amount of time before the server returns *_id* and loop goes to the next round by that time. Therefore, I need a way to wait for the server response and only after that move to the next round of the loop.

Here is my back-end code:

```
router.post("/createQuestion", (req, res) => {
  const newQuestion = new Question({
    description: req.body.description,
    type: req.body.type, 
    model: req.body.model
  });
  newQuestion.save().then(question => res.json(question._id))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Here is my axios function, which is in a separate file and imported into the class:

```
export const createQuestion = (questionData) => dispatch => {
  axios.post("/api/scorecard/createQuestion", questionData)
    .then(res => {
      return res.data;
    }).catch(err =>
         console.log("Error adding a question")
    );
};
```

Here is my code inside my class:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(i)).map(question => {
      const newQuestion = {
        description: question.description,
        type: question.questionType,
        model: this.props.model
      }
       const question_id =  this.props.createQuestion(newQuestion);
       console.log(question_id);
}
```

Console shows *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue i solved the same by sending the array question to the node and read one by one question and update with the next Question ID.

```
router.post("/createQuestion", (req, res) => {
let d =[questionarray];
let i = 0;
        let length = d.length;
        var result = [];
        try {
            const timeoutPromise = (timeout) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                await timeoutPromise(1000);   // 1000 = 1 second
                let CAT_ID = parseInt(d[i].CAT_ID);
                let TOPIC_ID = parseInt(d[i].TOPIC_ID);
                let Q_DESC = (d[i].Q_DESC);
                let OPT_1 = (d[i].OPT_1);
                let OPT_2 = (d[i].OPT_2);
                let OPT_3 = (d[i].OPT_3);
                let OPT_4 = (d[i].OPT_4);
                let ANS_ID = (d[i].ANS_ID);
                let TAGS = (d[i].TAGS);
                let HINT = (d[i].HINT);
                let LEVEL = d[i].LEVEL;
                let SRNO = d[i].SrNo;
                let qid;

                const savemyData = async (data) => {
                    return await data.save()

                }
                var myResult = await Question.find({ TOPIC_ID: TOPIC_ID }).countDocuments(function (err, count) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (count === 0) {
                            qid = TOPIC_ID + '' + 10001;
                            const newQuestion = new Question({
                                Q_ID: qid,
                                CAT_ID: CAT_ID,
                                TOPIC_ID: TOPIC_ID,
                                Q_ID: qid,
                                Q_DESC: Q_DESC,
                                OPT_1: OPT_1,
                                OPT_2: OPT_2,
                                OPT_3: OPT_3,
                                OPT_4: OPT_4,
                                ANS_ID: ANS_ID,
                                HINT: HINT,
                                TAGS: TAGS,
                                LEVEL: LEVEL,
                                Q_IMAGE: ''
                            })

                            await savemyData(newQuestion)
                                .then(result => { return true })
                                .catch(err => { return false });
                            //`${SRNO} is added successfully`
                            //`${SRNO} is Failed`

                        }

                        else if (count > 0) {
                            //   console.log(count)
                            Question.find({ TOPIC_ID: TOPIC_ID }).sort({ Q_ID: -1 }).limit(1)
                                .then(question => {
                                    qid = question[0].Q_ID + 1;
                                    const newQuestion = new Question({
                                        Q_ID: qid,
                                        CAT_ID: CAT_ID,
                                        TOPIC_ID: TOPIC_ID,
                                        Q_ID: qid,
                                        Q_DESC: Q_DESC,
                                        OPT_1: OPT_1,
                                        OPT_2: OPT_2,
                                        OPT_3: OPT_3,
                                        OPT_4: OPT_4,
                                        ANS_ID: ANS_ID,
                                        HINT: HINT,
                                        TAGS: TAGS,
                                        LEVEL: LEVEL,
                                        Q_IMAGE: ''
                                    })
                                    await savemyData(newQuestion)
                                        .then(result => { return true })
                                        .catch(err => { return false });

                                })
                                .catch(err => console.log(err));
                        }
                    }
                });
                if (myResult)
                    result.push(`${SRNO} is added successfully`);
                else
                    result.push(`${SRNO} is Failed`);
            }
            //      console.log(result)
            return res.json(result);
        }
        catch (err) {
            //res.status(404).json({ success: false })
            console.log(err)
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First your function `createQuestion` doesn't return a value so the assigning to question_id would always be undefined. Anyways, since u have a dispatch in your `createQuestion` function, I am assuming u r using `redux`, so I would suggest you to using `redux-thnk`, split the fetching new action logic to a thunk action, and use the questionID value from the `redux` state rather than returning a value from `createQuestion`. In your class u can be listening for a change of the `questionID` and if that happens, dispatch the saving of the next question.

Comment: I have edited my code, so my function createQuestion() has a return value now. Could you suggest me how can I get that value to my variable?